# Use of unresolved identifier 'Singleton' Swift 3

Tags: iphone, swift, swift3

Here is my below code:

```
private static var __once: () = {
            Singleton.instance = RtccManager()
            if let instance = Singleton.instance {
                instance.connectionParameters = instance.flattenConnectionParametersOverride(nil)
                instance.currentStat = .sta_notConnected
                DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.background).async {
                    instance.rtccConnect([:])
                }
            }
        }()

    var connectionParameters: [String : Any] = [:]
    var currentStat: AppStatus = AppStatus.sta_notConnected

    class var sharedInstance: RtccManager {
        struct Singleton {
            static var instance: RtccManager? = nil
            static var token: Int = 0
        }
        _ = RtccManager.__once

        return Singleton.instance!
    }
```

I am getting error on line `Singleton.instance = RtccManager()` and line

`if let instance = Singleton.instance`

Error is: Use of unresolved identifier 'Singleton'
This error came after migrating to Swift 3.0

Any ideas on how can I resolve this error's?

Comment: You have defined `Singleton` inside `sharedInstance` ... wrong scope.

Comment: @EricAya: Thank you so much, my bad I misunderstood :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're migrating your code It's should be a good idea to adapt your singleton creation mode to the *new way* suggested by Apple in their [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html).

Here's an example

```
public class RtccManager
{
    /*
        Nested types
    */
    public enum AppStatus
    {
        case sta_connected
        case sta_notConnected
    }

    public static let sharedInstance: RtccManager = RtccManager()

    public private(set) var connectionParameters: [String: Any]
    public private(set) var currentStat: AppStatus

    private init()
    {
        self.connectionParameters = [String: Any]()
        // flattenConnectionParametersOverride
        self.currentStat = .sta_notConnected
    }
}
```